# How to switch to next \ previous property in properties window without using a mouse in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, shortcut

The topic says it all. In case of my question is not clear enough let me provide you a screenshot ;-)

[Property Window http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/7682/propwindow.png](http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/7682/propwindow.png)

I am editing `ColumnHeadersHeight` property. When I finish I want to use some a key to go to `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle` property or to `ColumnHEadersHeightSizeMode` property. How to do that **without** using a mouse?

Comment: @Simon That is a most ridiculous vote down I've ever seen. Of course it is a programming question, it concerns an IDE which is used to write programs. However, I fully respect your rights to downvote ;-)

Comment: It's about the usage of a standard windows control.

Comment: @Than I assume that you are downvoting all questions about various IDE features and shortcuts, right? ;) On your right you have related questions, 90% of them should be downvoted by your logic ;)

Comment: Most of those questions are targeting visual studio as IDE. You were asking about the usage of a standard windows control. It's like asking: "How can I press a button without using the mouse?" You don't have to use VS2010 in order to ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit enter and then use the arrow keys to move up and down.  Then hit tab to select the value for what ever property you want to change

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to mention that tab does not have to be pressed. user can start to type right away after switching a property and its value will get edited.